# how to show cross hair in highchart always by default

Tags: highcharts

I want to show cross hair by default in high chart not any event but it should always be there. How to show crosshair at every x-axis point in highchart?

Comment: Take a look at axis.plotLines functionality. You can add plotLines for every point - see available options in the official API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineWidth

Comment: At every x axis point? You are referring to `gridLines`, X Axis grid lines have a width of `0` by default - set the width as desired.  Ref: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineWidth

Comment: thanks @morganfree and jibriggs. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Using highcharts api**

The mouse course will change to crosshair when over a point on the chart

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    alert('You just clicked the graph');
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

[using api jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/russellmazonde/qgmwpo6j/)

**Using jquery**

This will make the mouse cursor be a cross hair whenever its on the graph.

```
$("#container").css( 'cursor', 'crosshair' );
```

[using jquery jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/russellmazonde/pxw4eoc4/)

Comment: Hi this is not what is required. In highchart crosshair means.See this http://jsfiddle.net/k8msjmbx/ here crosshair comes on mouse hover I want it to be always there.